# AngularJS ui-router not rendering view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I've been struggling with getting my AngularJS app to display a view based on a template.

**The issue:** ui-router seems to be correctly "routing" all the files, because the template file (`landing.html`) is being delivered to the console as an object (see `console.log(result)` in `main.js` below). Nevertheless, the template file is not being displayed in the app where `<div ui-view></div>` is supposed to be.

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
@@include('partials/head.html')
<body>

  @@include('partials/header.html')

      <div ui-view></div>

  @@include('partials/footer.html')
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js:**

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ui.router'
])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('landing', {
      url: '/',
        controller: 'LandingCtrl as landing',
        templateUrl: 'templates/landing.html'
    });
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/landing');

}])
  .run(['$http', '$templateCache', function($http, $templateCache) {

    $http.get('templates/landing.html', {
      cache: $templateCache
    }).then(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    });

  }]);
```

My template file **landing.html:**

```
<main class="content">

    @@include('partials/search.html')
    <h2>Show me the contents of landing.html!</h2>

</main>
```

I'm using grunt and made sure to have it both watch and copy the `/templates` into `/dist`. Overall the Angular app is behaving correctly (no ng errors in the console).

Also, if instead of specifying a template file (`templateURL`), I simply use `template: <h2>Show me the contents of landing.html!</h2>` in `main.js` then this is rendered in the view. There's something preventing a file from being rendered.

**Question:** Given ui-router is correctly finding and routing all files, does anyone have an idea as to why the app is simply not displaying the template file?

**Edit** Here is `LandingCtrl.js`:

```
(function() {
  function LandingCtrl($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {   
    $scope.goTo = function(id) {
      $location.hash(id);
      console.log($location.hash());
      $anchorScroll();
    };    
  }    
  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('LandingCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$anchorScroll', LandingCtrl]);
})();
```

Comment: Why are using @@include?

Comment: hi @Vivz, I'm using HTML partials because otherwise some of my files would be much longer. I tried various times to exclude them to see whether they made any difference but didn't get a different result so far.

Comment: Your ui-view will trigger the partails based on your state

Comment: @Vivz, could you please clarify a little... when I run the app as is, the partials in `index.html` are visible and functional as they should be. There is also a partial in `landing.html` but since the entire file is not being rendered, it makes no difference whether there is partial inside of this file or not.

Comment: Where is the controller code? maybe the controller is thrown an error and it is not rendering the view.

Comment: @Valter, I posted the controller code above. No ng errors in console though, but maybe there's something wrongly declared? I had implemented `$anchorScroll` to get a "jump to top" link to work correctly.

Comment: @orlando21, where are you injection the $anchorScroll module. I don't see it. You have to inject the $anchorScroll into the app so you can use it in the controller.

Comment: @Valter, thanks for the tip. I've been using $anchorScroll in the controller as such with no errors. Should I try to inject it in `angular.module`?

Comment: I was confused with another module... $anchorScoll is part of the main AngularJs Module and it should work... Have you try with an empty/blank controller? Do you see the console.log($location.hash()) on the console

Comment: Why you doing this: controller: 'LandingCtrl as landing', why "as landing"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your main.js file change the url of `Landing State` as below:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ui.router'
])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('landing', {
      url: '/landing',
        controller: 'LandingCtrl as landing',
        templateUrl: 'templates/landing.html'
    });
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/landing');

}])
  .run(['$http', '$templateCache', function($http, $templateCache) {

    $http.get('templates/landing.html', {
      cache: $templateCache
    }).then(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    });

  }]);
```

Comment: Ok, so in `$stateProvider.state`, I replace `url: /` with `url: /landing`. Awesome, it works. Thanks!